# Laptop keeps powering off randomly?

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop

Ok so this has been going on for a while now but recently seems to be happening more frequently. I have an Acer Aspire 5750G with core i5 and NVIDIA GeForce GT520M running Windows 7. This laptop has been randomly powering off without warning which is very fustrating. Doesnt say shutting down or anything just black screen and it is off. Just now when I turned it on again I was about to login when the screen froze and started flickering with black lines on the screen. I tried to turn it on again and when I tried to type my password my laptop turned off and rebooted itself (it usually stays off until I turn it on again myself). Now, everytime I try to login it just turns itself off. Can someone please help me and tell me what the problem is? I just tried to boot into safe mode now and when I try to type a password it turns off.
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like it is overheating. Have you ejected the dust bunnies from their home recently?

Comment: Is your laptop over heated?. This could due to the internal fan is not functioning properly and which spreads heavy heat on and around the CPU, which can lead to this situation

Comment: definitely sounds like it's overheating.  Is it hot to the touch?

Comment: I know this sounds wierd but it only seems to be happening when the charger is plugged in... Seems like im going to have to charge it first and use it after, although the battery is worn out anyway. I checked CPU and GPU temperatures and they were both around 40/45 celsius on idle.